# Creating a custom context

Tags: 6, chaos-tool-suite

I want to create a custom context. However I can't seem to get it working. I have seen the following from api.text.

Adding a condition or reaction plugin
 Both context conditions and reactions utilize the CTools plugins API.
 In order to add a new condition or reaction for your module, follow these steps:
1. Implement `hook_context_plugins()` to define your plugins, classes, and class   hierarchy.

> ```
> function mymodule_context_plugins() {
>   $plugins = array();
>   $plugins['mymodule_context_condition_bar'] = array(
>     'handler' => array(
>       'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') .'/plugins',
>       'file' => 'mymodule_context_condition_bar.inc',
>       'class' => 'mymodule_context_condition_bar',
>       'parent' => 'context_condition',
>      ),
>   );
>   return $plugins;
> }
> ```

1. Implement 
   hook_context_registry() to define your conditions and/or reactions and map them to plugins.

> ```
> function mymodule_context_registry() {
>   return array(
>      'conditions' => array(
>        'bar' => array(
>           'title' => t('Name of condition "bar"'),
>           'plugin' => 'mymodule_context_condition_bar',
>         ),
>      ),
>   );
> }
> ```

1. Write your condition or reaction plugin class. It's best to look at oneof the included plugins as a starting point.

   1. Add in a Drupal integration point for your plugin. A node page condition plugin, for example, may be invoked from `hook_nodeapi()`.

I have also found the following http://treehouseagency.com/blog/neil-hastings/2010/04/14/joy-extending-context.

However when I go to `/admin/build/context/add` I do not see my condition listed in the Condition drop down.

I have tried `drush cc all`

Can anyone point out anything I can read and/or a working code sample.

In the end I want to fire a condition on `hook_nodapi` when the node is views and a certain type. I was going to pass the `$node` to the `execute($value)` and then do the remaining checks.

Comment: you need to write your .inc file. If it does not exist the condition will not appear in the Context UI.